# Show all user accounts on greeter screen

Tags: kubuntu, login, 15.10, lightdm, sddm

Is there a way to have Kubuntu 15.10 default to showing **all** users known to the system on the  login screen (greeter)?

If I have users Alf, Bill, Chris, Daisy and Ella, and Daisy was the last user when the system shut down, then on the next system start, the log in screen gets centered around Daisy's icon. Ella appears to the right, Chris to the left, but Alf and Bill are hidden behind time & date. Alf and Bill need to know that they are expected to grasp the user list and drag it to the right to find their icons, which is more than confusing.

Comment: Which display manager do you use ? I see the tag  lightdm on your topic. Is it  correct? You can check it with the command: cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager

Comment: Well, sorry, obviously I set a wrong tag; thank you for your hint. default-display-manager points to sddm. Probably I was misled by the German Wikipedia page for Kubuntu, which conceals the switch to SDDM. Maybe looking for a solution for my problem in the LightDM arena was one reason for not finding one <g>. Should I switch to LightDM or can SDDM be adjusted to my needs?

Comment: I don't know  very well SDDM (it's new!) maybe it's possible too. But in the others display manager like (gdm,lightdm,...) there is a parameter name "userlist" that you can enable/disable .

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, I've come to the conclusion (everybody feel free to correct me) that the SDDM/Breeze theme combination which Kubuntu 15.10 installs by default offers no parameter to adjust the user list appearance. I only found a partial, quick and dirty (mainly dirty) way to recover some additional space for the list: Fiddling around with the file UserSelect.qml in /usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/components/ - commenting out InfoPane therein, changing the left anchor of UserList to parent.left and dropping its leftMargin.

Comment: There are other SDDM-Themes that  obviously offer the required capability.

sddm-theme-maui / sddm-theme-malvines

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints. But "SDDM-Themes that obviously offer the required capability" - do they? I only found a video for maui [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJ28mrOeuNA) and it appears to me that it shows the very same limitation.

Comment: If the given themes don't offer enough features for you I would just recommend that you place a feature-request within the projects, the more clear/precise you are about the graphical layout the better chance exists that this get's implemented in newer versions of Plasma/SDDM. Even better if you have some knowledge in QML-programming.

https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues
https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=sddm

Just keeping in mind that you are on Plasma 5.3.x/SDDM 0.11 in Wily, means that such issues may already have been reported and _eventually_ been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your proposals. However, I just hoped to be able to replace a Windows setup by Linux without too much effort. Looks that this is not the case, and I invested already too much time into this job. Will have to live with that  less-than-ideal solution. Thanks again to everybody who helped out.